# Access private properties and methods from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used the [jQuery Boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/) template as starting point for a jQuery plug-in. This template provides a set up where `this` represents the plug-in instance and gives access to properties and methods:

```
init: function() {
    $(this.element).css({borderColor: "red"});
    this.drawMarker([100, 200]);
},
drawMarker: function(coordinates) {
    if (this.settings.isAbsolute) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now I need to handle some mouse clicks and it's all getting really confusing because callback functions redefine the `this` variable to represent the clicked event so, in order to access the plugin stuff, I came up with this ugly workaround:

```
this.container.on("click", "." + this.settings.markerClass,
        {plugin: this}, this.removeMarker);
```

... and:

```
removeMarker: function(event){
    var plugin = event.data.plugin;
    var marker = $(this);
    if (plugin.settings.isAbsolute) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is this actually what I'm supposed to do or I'm overlooking a most straightforward approach?

Comment: Do not know if it would be worse than what you got, but you could always use `bind` to change the context back to your plugin, and then just get your element from `event.target`, or use the [.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) jQuery function

Comment: @PatrickEvans - You are right, `this.$container.on("click", "." + this.settings.markerClass, $.proxy(this.removeMarker, this))` is definitively a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function (added on 1.4) to force a given context inside event handlers:

```
this.$container.on("click", "." + this.settings.markerClass,
    $.proxy(this.removeMarker, this));
```

Then, the stuff you need can be reached as follows:

- Plugin properties/methods: `this`
- Clicked element: `event.target` (on delegated events, it's [the precise element the user clicked on](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/); the one we normally want)

```js
removeMarker: function(event){
    var $marker = $(event.target);
    if (this.settings.isAbsolute) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

*This technique is courtesy of [Patrick Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560593/patrick-evans).*

Comment: Also a good note about `$.proxy` is that it helps in the removal of the listener as you can just pass the original function. Where as with just `bind` you cannot pass the original function and still remove the listener. Which I actually didn't even think about till fully reading the proxy docs and it mentioning the removal ability.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access privately scoped variables (using functions that are therefore by definition not on the plugins `prototype`) just create an additional variable that aliases the plugin object:

```
var plugin = this;

this.container.on('click', function() {
    // use plugin here
    ...
});
```

If the callback function in question is on the prototype, you can access the object within the callback thus:

```
var plugin = $(element).data('plugin_' + pluginName);
```

Comment: Do you mean to create a variable in the outer scope (at the same level than e.g. `pluginName`) and always use that alias?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yes, pretty much.

Comment: It's being really tricky. If I declare it beside `pluginName` or at `function Plugin(){}` then it's shared among all instances. Inside  `init: function(){}` it's unreachable from sibling methods...